# I get error with my 8psk modulation code

Tags: matlab, modulation

I'am trying to code a 8PSK modulation system,this is the code:

```
custMap = [0 2 4 6 7 5 3 1];
hChan = comm.AWGNChannel('BitsPerSymbol',log2(8));
hErr = comm.ErrorRate;
% Initialize the simulation vectors. The Eb/No is varied from 0 to 10 dB in
% 1 dB steps.
ebnoVec = 0:10;
for k = 1:length(ebnoVec)
      % Set the channel Eb/No
      hChan.EbNo = ebnoVec(k);
      while errVec(2) < 200 && errVec(3) < 1e7
          % Generate a 1000-symbol frame
          data = randi([0 1],4000,1);
          modData = step(hMod,data);
          % Pass the modulated data through the AWGN channel
          rxSig = step(hChan,modData);
          % Demodulate the received signal
          rxData = step(hDemod,rxSig);
      end

  end
```

but I have a problem at this line:

```
modData = step(hMod,data);
```

this is the error:
[image]
how can I solve the problem please and thanks for any Help

Comment: I can't run the code, `comm` is undefined.

Comment: @Daniel comm is a package that you can find it in the latest versions of matlab,I use matlab 2013 :)

Answer (score 1):

You have configured your communication channel to use 3 bits/symbol. Your error is here:

```
% Generate a 1000-symbol frame
data = randi([0 1],4000,1);
```

For 1000 symbols, you must generate 3000 bits.